# Height position different in Fireforx as Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, position

I don't got the same result in Chrome and Firefox. Also in Chrome is my image on the right position, but in Firefox the image is 10px higher.

I tried many combinations with position and display, but in Firefox its still not on the right position.

HTML:

```
    <div class="icopic">
        <center><img src="img/pin_logo.ico" /></center>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.icopic img {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-top: 770px;
margin-left: 15px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a margin/padding reset @ the top of your css? `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` this will zero out margin and padding for all elements not specifically styled below tht rule.

Comment: Yes, i tried already... but no effect on my problem.

Comment: Issues like this I suggest posting a snippit that will reproduce the issue in your question.

Comment: This is right: https://ibb.co/6nZdRvL (chrome)
This is false: https://ibb.co/NLnPKLd (firefox)

Comment: Use   https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: normalize.css doesnt help.